# Before-after measurement and ordinal longitudinal analysis

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, ordered-logit, pre-post-comparison

Two types of treatment were considered to relieve pain after surgery. 
Pain is measured as follows:
 first 30 min after first interpleural (IP) injection (hour zero) in recovery room,  then every 4 hours in resting position **before and 30 min after** IP injection (i.e., hours 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, and 24 postoperatively) in ICU using faces pain scale.

However,

1. The repeated measurements are both **before-after** and **longitudinal** (0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20 and 24 hours).
2. The dependent variable (pain) is recorded on an ordinal scale, and we can't subtract  difference before-after use this difference in ordinal logistic models.

Which analysis is better to highlight the difference between the two treatment groups?

Comment: (1) there was no for data analysis plan this study? even the IRB document should contain some minimal elements of a data analysis plan. (2) what do you feel your options are? (3) you haven't really described how pain is evaluated. Sounds like 6 ordinal categories, but unclear (4) have you done a simple plot of the data?

Comment: This pain scale was defined as score 0: no pain, score 1-2: mild, score 3-5: moderate, score 6: discomforting, score 7: distressing, score 8-9: horrible, score 10: excruciating.

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/593483/86652) seems rather closely related regarding the nature of the experiment (i.e. analysis depends on whether this was a randomized study) and the ordinal nature of the assessments (ordinal regression as an option, likely monotonic effect of baseline measurement on subsequent measurements).

The one extra-feature is the repeated post-intervention assessments. That has two aspects to it:

1. **What extra model terms might be needed to describe what is likely to be different between these different assessments?** For this, the conventional wisdom (applicable whether the outcome variable is ordinal or not) would be to add a timepoint main effect, a treatment by timepoint interaction, and a baseline by timepoint interaction to a regression model. That would be in addition to the treatment and baseline main effects you would already have.
2. **How to reflect that measurements on the same subject are correlated (and likely more correlated the closer together in time)?** For this, one would typically want to have a random(-subject) effect for each timepoint that would ideally be arbitrarily correlated (aka "unstructured correlation structure"). I.e. the random effect for each patient would be a 6-dimensional vector with a component for each assessment timepoint. As an approximation a random(-subject) effect on the intercept might do (i.e. a single scalar random effects value for each patient that's used for all timepoints).